# How do I use Angular Universal on Deno / Oak, for SSR Rendering and building hybrid MPAs?

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, deno, oak, multi-page-application

How do I use Angular Universal on Deno / Oak, for SSR Rendering and building hybrid MPAs?

Or am I choosing the wrong framework. I've already built some small sample routing in Deno / Oak (instead Node.js / Express), as it is newer.

But there is no documentation on how to use his with Oak.

I undersand you can use Angular (Components) with Astro, and then Astro on Deno, but I haven't found anything about using Angular Universal on Deno.

Both are powerful typescript frameworks (Angular) and (Oak on Deno) - so it makes sense to try to use both to create a hybrid MPA / SPA app.

ST